# How to refresh Azure AD B2C (Angular) SPA session data?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

**Scenario** :

I am logged-in through an AD B2C account in my Angular application.
I have integrated [msal-browser](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html) (^2.15.0) and [msal-angular](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/msal-angular/) (^2.0.1), for authentication and to access session data.

I use Graph API (from my .NET server) to update my AD B2C User record from my Angular application.

**Requirement** :

Whenever I update the User record through Graph APIs (indirectly through my server) from my Angular application, I want my browser session to reflect those changes as well.

```
// user-data.service.ts

public updateUserRecord(userUpdateObj: CustomUserModel) {
 this.http.put("https://my-server-calling-graph-api.com/user-data", userUpdateObj ,this.HTTP_OPTIONS)
  .pipe(
    map((updatedResult: CustomUserModel) => {
     console.log('Updated User Record -> ', updatedResult);

     // SESSION DATA
     this.usersList = this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts();
     this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(this.usersList[0]);
     const userCustomAttributes = this.usersList[0].idTokenClaims;

     console.log('Existing User Record -> ', userCustomAttributes);
    }),
    retry(2)
  );
} // FN
```

**Question** :
Is there a way to silently get the session data updated in the background through any msal service calls or should I redirect to login to receive the session data freshly?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve this is to call `acquireTokenRedirect()` or `ssoSilent()` MSAL method. These use cookie based logins which will then reprocess the user journey and fetch the latest data. `ssoSilent()` occurs in a hidden iframe. You may find, due to replication delays, that this still doesn't work reliably.

To avoid this issue, the end user can edit their user profile using an [Edit Profile flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-profile-editing-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). This would be the recommended path.